# How do you validate JwtSecurityToken that has been signed using Azure's WEBSITE_AUTH_SIGNING_KEY?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, jwt, azure-mobile-services

I have setup 3rd party login providers (google and microsoft) on Azure for my web app. I am adding a custom login also (in case the user doesn't have one of those accounts). I have the token being generated as follows:

```
private JwtSecurityToken GenerateToken(User user)
{
    var audience = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ValidAudience"];
    var issuer = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ValidIssuer"];

    JwtSecurityToken token = AppServiceLoginHandler.CreateToken(new Claim[] { new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Sub, user.AzureUserID) },
        GetSigningKey(),
        audience,
        issuer,
        TimeSpan.FromHours(1));

    return token;
}
```

Where GetSigningKey() returns a string of the Azure environment variable WEBSITE_AUTH_SIGNING_KEY. The default authentication with my API controllers is working great, but when I need to refresh my token due to it expiring I am having trouble validating its signature. There are a lot of examples out there on how to validate JwtSecurityTokens, but I haven't been able to find any when you signed it using the WEBSITE_AUTH_SIGNING_KEY. Here is what I have tried to get working, without success:

```
var validationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
{
    ValidAudience = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ValidAudience"],
    ValidIssuer = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ValidIssuer"],
    IssuerSigningToken = <I think I need this, but not sure how to populate it...>,

    ValidateAudience = true,
    ValidateIssuer = true,
    ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true
};

SecurityToken validatedToken;
tokenHandler.ValidateToken(expiredAccessToken, validationParameters, out validatedToken);
```

Does anyone have any ideas on how to validate the token?

Answer (score 0):

App Settings (including the signing key you mentioned) appear as environment variables, so you can either use the ConfigurationManager to read it or you can use the normal environment variable reading for ASP.NET

Try:

```
ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["WEBSITE_AUTH_SIGNING_KEY"]
```

Comment: Thanks Adrian, but my question wasn't how to get that environment variable, it was how to read a JwtSecurityToken that had been secured with it already.

Comment: Within App Service, it is validated for you.  Check out the blog at http://cgillum.tech - it contains extensive details on what happens under the covers, so you can bypass validation and just read the claims from environment variables and/or /.auth/me endpoint.

Comment: I can bypass the authentication easily buy just removing the Authorize tag from my controller method. My case for wanting to do this is because I have my own custom login in addition to the build in providers (google & microsoft) and I need to refresh my token that has expired. My question was how do I still validate the token (which I can most certainly NOT skip doing, since any malicious user could be sending me a token) when it had been signed using the WEBSITE_AUTH_SIGNING_KEY. See my answer below for how I got this to work.

Answer (score 0):

Digging through the unit tests on GitHub for the [azure-mobile-apps-net-server](https://github.com/Azure/azure-mobile-apps-net-server/blob/master/test/Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Server.Authentication.Test/AppServiceTokenHandlerTests.cs) project, I found an AppServiceTokenHandler that does the trick:

```
// Validate that the token was generated by our server.
var validationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
{
    ValidAudience = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ValidAudience"],
    ValidIssuer = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ValidIssuer"],

    ValidateAudience = true,
    ValidateIssuer = true,
    ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
    ValidateLifetime = false // The token is valid for this test case whether or not it is expired.
};

ClaimsPrincipal claimsPrincipal;
if (AppServiceTokenHandler.TryValidateToken(validationParameters, expiredAccessToken, GetSigningKey(), out claimsPrincipal))
{
    // Token is validated
}
```